# How to Upload photo from mobile to Visual force page

Tags: apex, visualforce, javascript, custom-button

[image: Image Upload]

am having one field in my custom object.i have to Upload photos to that field Via Camera or Gallery from My Local Machine Folder and I need to Edit My Already Uploaded Pictures...(Note Max 3 Pics allowed) Like the above attached picture..

Here is VF Code:

```
  <apex:page docType="html-5.0"  Controller="FeedbackController"  
    showheader="False" sidebar="False"> 

 <script 
     src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.0/jquery.min.js">
 </script>
  <script>
  $(document).ready(function(){
    $(".bPageBlock").css("background-color","papayawhip");
    $(".bPageBlock").css("border-color","papayawhip");
  });
  </script>
  <script>
  $(document).ready(function() {
  $("#photoFile").change(handlePhoto);
    });

     function handlePhoto(evt){
      var file = evt.target.files[0];
     var reader = new FileReader();

    reader.onload = (function(theFile) {
    return function(e) {
    // Extract raw base64 data from data URL
    imageData = e.target.result.split(',')[1];

  forcetkClient.create('ContentVersion', {
    "Origin": "H",
    "PathOnClient": file.name;,
    "VersionData": imageData
    }, function(data) {
    $('#status').html("<p>Uploaded image</p>");
    }, function(error){
    alert(JSON.stringify(error));
    });
    };
    })(file);

      reader.readAsDataURL(file);
    }

   </script>
  <script>
  function showPciklistval(){
  var myPicklistVal = document.getElementById("
  {!$component.myPicklist1}").value; //id of the apex:inputfield picklist 
 field
 alert('myPicklistVal==='+myPicklistVal);

 }
 </script>

 <style>
 body{ background-color:papayawhip;}
 </style>
 <apex:form > 
<html>
<head>
<title>Questionnaire3</title>
<style>
   div.btnGroup{
  text-align: center;margin-top:125px;margin-right:250px;padding:8px*20px;
   }

  div.btnGroup1{
  text-align:right;margin-top:-24px;margin-right:450px;padding:8px*20px;
   }

 div.btnGroup2{
 text-align:left;margin-top:160px;margin-left:125px;padding:8px*20px;font-
  size:150%
  }

 div.btnGroup3{
 text-align:center;margin-top:100px;margin-right:10px;padding:8px*20px;
 }

 body .bPageBlock .pbHeader {
background-color: Green; 
}
</style>
```

```
   <div class="btnGroup2">  
  <label for="Feed Back">YOUR FEEDBACK <br/><br/><br/></label> 
  <apex:pageBlock >
  <apex:pageBlockSection > 
 <apex:inputField id="myPicklist1" required="true" value="
{!Fed.X3_Are_you_satisfied_with_Logistics__c}"/><br /> <br /> 
  <apex:outputField value="{!Fed.Registered_Email__c}"/>
   <apex:inputFile value="{!cont.VersionData}" fileName="{!cont.Title}" 
accept="image/*;capture=camera"/>
      <input id="photoFile" type="file" accept="image/*"/>
  </apex:pageBlockSection>
</apex:pageBlock>
   </div>

<div class="btnGroup3">          
   <apex:commandButton action="{!Questionnaire3}" value="Next page" 
    onclick="showPciklistval()"  styleClass="buttonStyle" 
   style="background:lightcoral ;width:120px;height:25px;font-size: 13px"/> 
   <apex:actionFunction name="myActionfuncton" action="{!Questionnaire3}"/>     
   <button onclick="showPciklistval()">Click me</button>
</div>
</body>
</html>
</apex:form>
```

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: am having one field in my custom object.i have to Upload photos to that field Via Camera or Gallery from My Local Machine Folder and I need to Edit My Already Uploaded Pictures...

Comment: That still is not a question. Where are you stuck? Please update your question instead of comments.